# Write log with correct encoding for log4j in grails

Tags: grails, encoding, log4j

I tried to write cyrillic into my log file. But I can not find where I can define encoding for log file or how to write the correct way.

My appender configuration:

```
        file name: 'log', file: "logs/log.${new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Date.newInstance())}"
    appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
            name: 'dailyAppender',
            datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",  // See the API for all patterns.
            fileName: "logs/iv.${new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Date.newInstance())}",
            layout: pattern(conversionPattern:'%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n')
    )
```

Му Log calling

```
log.info "абв"
```

Log file result

```
`???`
```

File encoding is ANSI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
        name: 'dailyAppender',
        datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",  // See the API for all patterns.
        fileName: "logs/iv.${new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Date.newInstance())}",
        layout: pattern(conversionPattern:'%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x - %m%n'),
        encoding: 'UTF-8'
)
```

You must add : `encoding: 'UTF-8'`